# Map Data in MongoDB Aggregation pipeline

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is the data returned from my aggregation pipeline:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "data" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c8266b8d8c9cd7a89babac6"),
        "updatedBy" : ObjectId("5c2076d62781881e8764a47a"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-03-08T13:33:21.659Z"),
        "createdBy" : ObjectId("5c2076d62781881e8764a47a"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-03-08T12:57:28.683Z"),
        "productName" : "Yellow powder",
        "sku" : "563453534",
        "upc" : "903453453245",
        "__v" : 0,
        "brand" : "",
        "category" : "yellow category",
        "group" : "",
        "handle" : "yellow-grey",
        "imageUrl" : "",
        "inciRawText" : "",
        "specialtyText" : ""
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "data" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c7692433dcd874313b9fddb"),
        "sku" : "TESTSKU9",
        "__v" : 0,
        "brand" : "test brand",
        "category" : "test category",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-02-27T13:36:03.027Z"),
        "group" : "testgroup",
        "handle" : "mewo9",
        "imageUrl" : "",
        "inciRawText" : "Inci Raw Text. Long memo field",
        "productName" : "TEST9PROD",
        "publishStatus" : "Unpublished",
        "specialtyText" : "* denotes organic",
        "upc" : "TESTUPC9",
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-02-27T13:36:03.027Z")
    }
}
```

The aggregation pipeline is too big that's why I didn't wanted to add it here. I hope it's ok to omit that part.
Now I want to project this data to something like this using MongoDB Aggregation

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c8266b8d8c9cd7a89babac6"),
        "updatedBy" : ObjectId("5c2076d62781881e8764a47a"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-03-08T13:33:21.659Z"),
        "createdBy" : ObjectId("5c2076d62781881e8764a47a"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-03-08T12:57:28.683Z"),
        "productName" : "Yellow powder",
        "sku" : "563453534",
        "upc" : "903453453245",
        "__v" : 0,
        "brand" : "",
        "category" : "yellow category",
        "group" : "",
        "handle" : "yellow-grey",
        "imageUrl" : "",
        "inciRawText" : "",
        "specialtyText" : ""
    }, {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c7692433dcd874313b9fddb"),
        "sku" : "TESTSKU9",
        "__v" : 0,
        "brand" : "test brand",
        "category" : "test category",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-02-27T13:36:03.027Z"),
        "group" : "testgroup",
        "handle" : "mewo9",
        "imageUrl" : "",
        "inciRawText" : "Inci Raw Text. Long memo field",
        "productName" : "TEST9PROD",
        "publishStatus" : "Unpublished",
        "specialtyText" : "* denotes organic",
        "upc" : "TESTUPC9",
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-02-27T13:36:03.027Z")
    }
```

I'm sure there must be a method to do it, I'm trying to do it using $map operator, but still unable to get it done.

Can anyone please suggest me some solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) aggregation operator

```
db.produce.aggregate( [
   {
     $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" }
   }
] )
```